# Grails with MongoDB - how to define nested and reusable fields

Tags: mongodb, grails, groovy

I'm trying to rewrite my node.js + express backend in grails. I'm using a MongoDB database, where it is common to nest fields. In my current backend I have defined a schema (using mongoose), with a field such as:

```
normalized: {
    full_name: {type: String, trim: true, index: true}
},
```

I have also defined a separate, reusable schema called "locationSchema" that I can use for many of my fields, like so:

```
// Definition of reusable "sub-schema"
const locationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    country: {type: String, trim: true},
    region: {type: String, trim: true},
    city: {type: String, trim: true},
    notes: String,
    latitude: {type: Number},
    longitude: {type: Number}
}, {_id: false});
```

Which is then used, for example, to define the `birth` field:

```
birth: {
    date: {type: dateSchema, validate: dateValidator},
    location: locationSchema,
    notes: String
},
```

I did not manage to find much information on this, other than that it is possible to define nested fields as `Map`s, but how would I apply constraints to the sub-fields? And how would I use "sub-schemas" in Grails?

---

**UPDATE WITH SOLUTION**

I misunderstood the use of `embedded`. If you (like me) do not want to create tables/collections for embedded types, simply put the embedded class (like `Location` in my case) under `src/main/...` or define it in the same file as the domain class. This is stated in the documentation: http://docs.grails.org/3.1.1/ref/Domain%20Classes/embedded.html

My final, simplified solution is then:

**grails-app/.../Person.groovy**

```
class Person implements MongoEntity<Testy> {

    ObjectId id
    String s
    Location location

    static mapping = {
        collection "person"

    }

    static embedded = ['location']  // key part that was missing
}
```

**src/main/.../Location.groovy**

```
package hegardt.backend.grails.model.person

import grails.validation.Validateable


class Location implements Validateable {

    String country
    String region
    String city
    String notes
    Double latitude
    Double longitude

    static constraints = {
        country nullable: true
        region nullable: true
        city nullable: true
        notes nullable: true
        latitude nullable: true
        longitude nullable: true
    }
}
```

Now I can send requests with JSON data, and the mapping and saving works correctly, as well as validation on my embedded types!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using [embedded](http://docs.grails.org/3.1.1/ref/Domain%20Classes/embedded.html) object for your case.

```
class User {

  Birth birth

  static embedded = [ 'birth' ]

}

class Birth {
  Date date
  Location location
  String notes

  static constraints = {
    date validator:dateValidator
  }
}
```

Then if you do:

```
User u = new User()
u.birth = new Birth(...)
u.save()
```

the `birth` will be saved as a sub-document in `User`.

If you say:

```
new Birth(...).save()
```

then the GORM creates a new collection and fills the record in as usual.

Comment: Would this not make birth a separate domain object with its own collection?

Comment: no, if you use it inside `User` only. if you say `new Birth().save()` then yes, it will create a new collection

Comment: So is there no way for groovy to automatically map `new Person({"first_name": "..", "birth": {...}})` correctly from json? And what about the Location inside the Birth? This seems extremely impractical for deeper nesting...

Comment: why? there are tons of ways to bind json to objects. starting from `new Person( json )` to more sophisticated `bind()` method available in controllers

Comment: In GORM you define structure of your documents by a series of domain models, which can be nested in any way you like. You can also insert sub-documents of arbitrary structure simply as `Map`